# Can't print to PDF using cups-pdf; used to work, now "failed to set file mode" printing as non-root

Tags: printing, pdf, cups, ghostscript

Here's something really odd: something that used to work fine in Debian, and then broke, even without a dist-upgrade.

I used to be able to use the CUPS PDF virtual printer to print anything to a PDF file. Now, it doesn't work: nothing shows up in ~/PDF when I print as an ordinary user. If I log into the CUPS administration interface and use that to print a test page to the printer, though, it works; the PDF shows up nicely in ~root/PDF. **But I want to be able to print to PDF as a non-root user...**

/var/log/cups/cups-pdf_log has this to say:

```
Fri Feb  7 18:31:57 2014  [STATUS] ***Experimental Option: DecodeHexStrings
Fri Feb  7 18:31:57 2014  [ERROR] failed to set file mode for PDF file (non fatal) (/michael/home/PDF/PDF_-_CUPS_1_5.pdf)
Fri Feb  7 18:31:57 2014  [STATUS] PDF creation successfully finished (michael)
```

OK, so there's `failed to set file mode for PDF file`. Googling for that, however, doesn't help much. I did find one web page that suggested changing the `Out` directory in /etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf, so I did (`Out /tmp/${USER}.cups-pdf`) and restarted CUPS, and when I try to print to PDF it picks up that change because it created such a directory, but then complained about the same error in the new location.

Despite seemingly being at the latest version (CUPS 1.5.3-5+deb7u1, CUPS-PDF 2.6.1-6, Debian Wheezy), I decided to reinstall CUPS just in case it had broken somehow.

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall -u install cups cups-pdf cups-bsd cups-client cups-common cups-driver-gutenprint cups-filters cups-pk-helper cups-ppdc
```

However, I am still getting the same error.

Setting `LogType 7` in /etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf produces this:

```
Fri Feb  7 19:01:29 2014  [DEBUG] switching to new gid (lpadmin)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:29 2014  [DEBUG] initialization finished (v2.6.1)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:29 2014  [DEBUG] user identified (michael)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:29 2014  [DEBUG] output directory name generated (/tmp/michael.cups-pdf)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:29 2014  [DEBUG] user information prepared
Fri Feb  7 19:01:29 2014  [DEBUG] spoolfile name created (/var/spool/cups-pdf/SPOOL/cups2pdf-18015)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:29 2014  [DEBUG] source stream ready
Fri Feb  7 19:01:29 2014  [DEBUG] destination stream ready (/var/spool/cups-pdf/SPOOL/cups2pdf-18015)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:29 2014  [DEBUG] owner set for spoolfile (/var/spool/cups-pdf/SPOOL/cups2pdf-18015)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:29 2014  [DEBUG] using traditional fgets
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] found beginning of postscript code (%!PS-Adobe-3.0)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] now extracting postscript code
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] found title in ps code ((What does the CUPS PDF printer need to be able to set file mode? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange))
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] found end of postscript code (%%EOF)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] all data written to spoolfile (/var/spool/cups-pdf/SPOOL/cups2pdf-18015)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] trying to use PS title ((What does the CUPS PDF printer need to be able to set file mode? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange))
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] removing trailing newlines from title ((What does the CUPS PDF printer need to be able to set file mode? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange))
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [STATUS] ***Experimental Option: DecodeHexStrings
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] checking for hex strings ((What does the CUPS PDF printer need to be able to set file mode? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange))
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] not a hex string, has no start marker ((What does the CUPS PDF printer need to be able to set file mode? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange))
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] removing enclosing parentheses () from full title ((What does the CUPS PDF printer need to be able to set file mode? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange))
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] calling alternate_replace_string
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] removing alternate special characters from title (What does the CUPS PDF printer need to be able to set file mode? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] truncating title (What_does_the_CUPS_PDF_printer_need_to_be_able_to_set_file_mode_)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] title successfully retrieved (What_does_the_CUPS_PDF_printer_need_to_be_able_to_set_file_mode_)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] input data read from stdin
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] output filename created (/tmp/michael.cups-pdf/What_does_the_CUPS_PDF_printer_need_to_be_able_to_set_file_mode_.pdf)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] ghostscript commandline built (/usr/bin/gs -q -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="/tmp/michael.cups-pdf/What_does_the_CUPS_PDF_printer_need_to_be_able_to_set_file_mode_.pdf" -dAutoRotatePages=/PageByPage -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -c .setpdfwrite -f /var/spool/cups-pdf/SPOOL/cups2pdf-18015)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] output file unlinked (/tmp/michael.cups-pdf/What_does_the_CUPS_PDF_printer_need_to_be_able_to_set_file_mode_.pdf)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] TMPDIR set for GhostScript (/var/tmp)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] waiting for child to exit
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] entering child process
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] GID set for current user
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] supplementary groups set for current user
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] UID set for current user (michael)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] ghostscript has finished (256)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [ERROR] failed to set file mode for PDF file (non fatal) (/tmp/michael.cups-pdf/What_does_the_CUPS_PDF_printer_need_to_be_able_to_set_file_mode_.pdf)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] ERRNO: 2
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] no postprocessing
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] spoolfile unlinked (/var/spool/cups-pdf/SPOOL/cups2pdf-18015)
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [DEBUG] all memory has been freed
Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [STATUS] PDF creation successfully finished (michael)
```

I do notice that it looks like Ghostscript is exiting with status 256 (`[DEBUG] ghostscript has finished (256)`), but I can't find anything that tells me why exactly it would exit with that error code.

My user account is not a member of the `lp` or `lpadmin` groups, but that hasn't changed.

Printing to the physical printer on my desk works fine; I did that just recently, long after printing to PDF started acting up like this.

What might be my problem?

Comment: Hi Michael, did you figure this one out? If so, add an update.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Unfortunately, not yet.

Answer (score 2):

Having Referred to the following post:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1975881

After many research, in the end I found my problem was the permission of the folder **`/var/tmp/`**, it was 755 (drwxr-xr-x, root, root).

After changing it to 777 (drwxrwxrwx), cups-pdf works again ..

Because in the **`/etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf`**, it is indicating either **`/var/tmp`** or **`/tmp`** must be user-writable!

Comment: Generally, global temporary directories should be mode `1777` (rwxrwxrwt), not `0777`. The sticky bit on a directory means that only the user who created a file can delete that file.

Comment: Thx! This was the relevant fix for our debian live distro, the `live-boot` scripts set the sticky bit only for `/tmp`; gonna submit a patch the other day..

Answer (score 1):

As you can see at this post: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/270046/comments/28

SOLVED by the easiest way (Disabling cups apparmor profile)

Run these commands ...

```
sudo mv /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd /etc/apparmor.d/disable
sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor restart
```

Comment: I didn't have apparmor installed in February, nor in May, and I still don't. While it is great that you want to contribute, please take a moment to read any existing answers before posting an answer of your own to make sure you aren't duplicating what someone has already posted; *particularly* something that someone has already posted which didn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

My users' home directories are in /local/home, so I had to change the line

```
@{HOMEDIRS}=/home/ /local/home/
```

in `/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home`.
Then restart apparmor with

```
sudo service apparmor restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your logs it sounds like there's an issue in setting permissions on the file in `/tmp`.

> Fri Feb  7 19:01:30 2014  [ERROR] failed to set file mode for PDF file (non fatal) (/tmp/michael.cups-pdf/What_does_the_CUPS_PDF_printer_need_to_be_able_to_set_file_mode_.pdf)

I'd confirm that you're able to do that. Perhaps the permissions on the parent directory, `/tmp`, got changed.

Comment: CUPS created that directory a few attempts before that, with mode 0700. /tmp is 1777 (double-checked). See the paragraph just below the first log snippet.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - a potential lead: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cupsys/+bug/147551. It's dated but looks like maybe an issue w/ apparmor?

Comment: Sorry, no apparmor installed at all here. So that's not it either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by changing 2 lines in `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd` (around line 156) to `/PDF/ rw`, and `/PDF/* rw`, to the output dir you want, then restarting apparmor & cups.

Comment: Good idea, and probably well worth capturing in an answer here, but as I mentioned in [this comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114077/cant-print-to-pdf-using-cups-pdf-used-to-work-now-failed-to-set-file-mode-p/127586?noredirect=1#comment176740_114081) I don't have apparmor installed on my system.

Answer (score 0):

This is 5 years late, but I believe the issue is with the ownership of the directory `michael.cups-pdf`. Use `chown` on the directory to match the ownership of the output files (ex: `nobody` if Anonymous).

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: His problem is right here. `[ERROR] failed to set file mode for PDF file (non fatal) (/tmp/michael.cups-pdf/What_does_the_CUPS_PDF_printer_need_to_be_able_to_set_file_mode_.pdf)` I had the same problem and I solved it by changing ownership of the directory cups-pdf was trying to write to.